# ThreadPoolWorkers that will not die if they create a thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, slack-api

In my Slack RTM message handler function, I am calling any one of a set of functions. Alone, each message event handler blocks the next, so I began to call these functions in new threads. After doing this, I cannot `exit()` my program, I am left with a `ThreadPoolExecutor-x_x` for each of the message handlers that were called.

Even if I set my threads to `setDaemon=True` and `.join()` to them, the ThreadPoolExecutors remain.

```py
    def exitFunc(sendfn, channel, thread, user, text, groups, groupdict, meta):
        reply = 'bye'
        sendfn(channel=channel, message = reply)
        for thread in threading.enumerate():
            print(thread.getName())
        exit()
```

Produces this, and hangs:

```
MainThread
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1
ThreadPoolExecutor-3_0
ThreadPoolExecutor-3_1
ThreadPoolExecutor-3_2
exitFunc
ThreadPoolExecutor-3_3
```

When I don't run the function as a new thread, these ThreadPoolExecutors seem to hang around but they do let my program exit.

Spawning the threads:

```py
def __init__(self, token, username = None, icon_emoji = None, security = None):
...
    slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')(self.readMessage)

def readMessage(self, **payload):
...
    thread = Thread(target=fn['fn'], kwargs = fnargs)
    thread.start()
```

the function passed in as sendfn:

```py
def sendMessage(self, channel, message, thread = None, username = None, icon_emoji = None):
    if username == None:
        username = self.default_username
    if icon_emoji == None:
        icon_emoji = self.default_icon_emoji

    print('{} Send to {}: {}'.format(str(datetime.now()), channel, message))

    self.webclient.chat_postMessage(
            channel=channel,
            text=message,
            username=username,
            icon_emoji=icon_emoji,
            thread_ts=thread
    )
```

I am using slackclient 2.0.1 python package.

Comment: what does your function `sendfn` do? Please add the source to your question. Also: Are you using any libraries for handling the Slack RTM?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an [XY problem.](http://xyproblem.info/)

It wasn't that my threads weren't dying, it was that I was trying to exit() from a thread.

> Since exit() ultimately “only” raises an exception, it will only exit
>   the process when called from the main thread, and the exception is not
>   intercepted.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit

I moved my exit to the main thread and it exited fine.